# Why my controller return html page, not JSON?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

So, i have problem, and does not have answer.
My rest controller that return html page

```
@Autowired
        private Gradebook gradebook;        
        
        @GetMapping( value= "/", produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
        public List<GradebookCollegeStudent> getStudents() {
            gradebook = studentService.getGradebook2();
            return gradebook.getStudents();
        }
```

My Test + exception

```
    @Test
    public void getStudentsHttpRequest() throws Exception {
        
        student.setFirstname("Chad");
        student.setLastname("Darby");
        student.setEmailAddress("chad@mail.com");
        entitymanage.persist(student);
        entitymanage.flush();
        
     

mock.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)));
            
    //java.lang.AssertionError: Content type expected:<application/json> but was:<text/html;charset=UTF-8>
}
```

How i try solve problem? i add `produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})` in controller, i set up MockHttpRespone before all tests, but problem still the same.

```
response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
```

Also i cannot understand where from my controller take index.html page that show in console after running test, because not one of my service does not return index!

```
gradebook = studentService.getGradebook2();  
 return gradebook.getStudents();
```

If somebody know real answer, please help !

Comment: As mentioned by @Trying my best, don't use "/" as your URI.  If you can't think of an reasonable URI, just use "/blueberry"

Comment: also i try endpoin "/blueberry" + change in test and status 404 expected 200

Answer (score 0):

Add to your test .header():

```
mock.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)));
```

Comment: Change endpoint to (/index), and status expected 200 but was 404

Comment: Can you do please what I said? Change in controller value=("/students") and in test  MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/students")

Comment: I understand that, i change @GetMapping( value= "/index", produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}), not /student, because endpoint /student is present, also i change MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/index") in my test, not "/student" because student is present

Comment: /index might be some default page, try another word.

Comment: i try /blueberry status 404 expected 200

Comment: Before that RestController , I had ordinary Controller 

 RequestMapping (value ="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getStudents (Model model) {
  Iterable <CollegeStudent2> collegeStudents = studentService.getGradebook();
  model.addAttribute("students", collegeStudents);
  return "index";
 }'
and everything work good, i want to write rest controller and my problem beginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252854/discussion-between-trying-my-best-and-jcoder).